# VB - If StreamReader reads line containing ("string1") but missing ("string2")

Tags: vb.net, string, contains

**EDIT:** *How would I go about retrieving the filename of the files that meet said conditions?*

How I can check if a string contains "value1" but doesn't have "value2"? I tried this:

```
While Not sr.EndOfStream
    Dim sLine As String = sr.ReadLine
    If sLine.Contains("value1") Then
        If Not sLine.Contains("value2") Then
            sw.WriteLine("write name of file that meets conditions to txt file")
End While
```

Not sure how to go about searching for the missing value.

Comment: Are you looking for `And` and `Not`? (see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET/Logical_operators#And)

Comment: The single line or the whole file?

Comment: it's for searching the whole file based on those conditions

Comment: Did you try  If sLine.Contains("value1") And Not sLine.Contains("value2") ?

Comment: So, if the Line number 1 contains the word 'value1' and the Line number 10 contains the word 'value2' you have found the correct file, otherwise if one of the two values is missing, you have an error?

Comment: @steve, yes, I'm reading a bunch of script files and want to log in a txtfile the name of the files that have value 1 but are missing value 2.

Comment: Then I think you have your answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could load the whole file in a string and do the check

```
If wholeFileData.Contains("value1") AndAlso Not wholeFileData.Contains("value2") Then
    sw.WriteLine("write name of file that meets conditions to txt file")
End If
```

If you are need to loop each line, then you'll need to store in a variable and show the message at the end.

```
Dim containsValue1, containsValue2 As Boolean

containsValue1 = False
containsValue2 = False

While Not sr.EndOfStream
    Dim sLine As String = sr.ReadLine

    If sLine.Contains("value1") Then
        containsValue1 = True
    End If

    If sLine.Contains("value2") Then
        containsValue2 = True
    End If
End While

If containsValue1 AndAlso Not containsValue2 Then
    sw.WriteLine("write name of file that meets conditions to txt file")
End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much! What would be the best way of retrieving the filename from the file beign read?

Comment: @Gmac There's no way for me to know how you are opening the file (it could be from a TCP/IP stream).

Answer (score 0):

```
If sLine.Contains("value1") = True and sLine.Contains("value2") = False Then
    Msgbox("sLine contains value1, but does not contain value2")
End If
```